# My matplotlib.pyplot legend is being cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create a plot with a legend to the side of it using matplotlib. I can see that the plot is being created, but the image bounds do not allow the entire legend to be displayed.

```
lines = []
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for filename in args:
    lines.append(plt.plot(y_axis, x_axis, colors[colorcycle], linestyle='steps-pre', label=filename))
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

This produces:
[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) provides an overview over several techniques that can be used to get the legend appear inside the figure boundaries.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As pointed by Adam, you need to make space on the side of your graph.
If you want to fine tune the needed space, you may want to look at the [add_axes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) method of matplotlib.pyplot.artist.

Below is a rapid example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

# plot of the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.75])
ax.plot(x, y1,'-k', lw=2, label='black sin(x)')
ax.plot(x, y2,'-r', lw=2, label='red cos(x)')
ax.set_xlabel('x', size=22)
ax.set_ylabel('y', size=22)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

and the resulting image: [image]

Comment: I know matplotlib likes to tout that everything is under the control of the user, but this entire thing with the legends is too much of a good thing. If I put the legend outside, I _obviously_ want it to still be visible. The window should just scale itself to fit instead of creating this huge rescaling hassle. At the very least there should be a default True option to control this autoscaling behavior. Forcing users to go through a ridiculous number of re-renders to try and get the scale numbers right in the name of control accomplishes the opposite.

Comment: @strpeter has provided an automatic solution in his answer that worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: i am looking at this code for minutes and still do not get which line fixes the problem

Comment: Did you read the text with my link to `add_axes`? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes I think the proposed solution is sufficiently well documented.

Answer (score 150):

Eventhough that it is late, I want to refer to a nice recently introduced alternative:

## New matplotlib feature: The tight bounding box

If you are interested in the output file of `plt.savefig`: in this case the flag `bbox_inches='tight'` is your friend!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1], label='A')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], label='B')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0))

fig.savefig('samplefigure', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Output file: samplefigure.png]

I want to refer also to a more detailed answer: [Moving matplotlib legend outside of the axis makes it cutoff by the figure box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154763/2062965)

## Advantages

- There is no need to adjust the actual data/picture.
- It is compatible with `plt.subplots` as-well where as the others are not!
- It applies at least to the mostly used output files, e.g. png, pdf.

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well w/ little modifications necessary.

Comment: @CarlodelMundo: What modifications were necessary in your case? Thanks for sharing them with us.

Comment: this should be the default for plt.savefig()

Comment: worked, thank you! Just for reference, here's the documentation from matplotlib:
> Bbox in inches. Only the given portion of the figure is saved. If 'tight', try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure. If None, use savefig.bbox

^^^ wtf does that even mean? whoever wrote this should get kicked in the face.

Comment: This should be the answer. Simple, to the point and gets the job done. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for this for ages!

Comment: Is there no equivalent for this for just plotting? `fig.tight_layout` doesn't do it.

Comment: What if we want to just do fig.show(), without saving? Even when I save the figure then show it, the legend is still cropped.

Comment: Thanks. tight works the best
fig.savefig(buffer, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')

Answer (score 12):

Just use `plt.tight_layout()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 0, 1], label='A')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2], label='B')
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0))

plt.tight_layout()
```

This is probably introduced in the newer `matplotlib` version and neatly does the job.

Comment: Right, this is how one would do it today with the more recent versions of `matplotlib`. For custom fine-tuning, the other options are still more appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way of making space (shrinking an axis):

```
# get the current axis
ax = plt.gca()
# Shink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
```

where 0.8 scales the width of the axis by 20%. On my win7 64 machine, using a factor greater than 1 will make room for the legend if it's outside the plot.

This code was referenced from: [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  @gcalmettes posted [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651897/42346).
His solution should probably be used instead of the method shown below.
Nonetheless I'll leave this since it sometimes helps to see different ways of doing things.

---

As shown in [the legend plotting guide](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/plotting/legend.html#plotting-guide-legend), you can make room for another subplot and place the legend there.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(121) # <- with 2 we tell mpl to make room for an extra subplot
ax.plot([1,2,3], color='red', label='thin red line')
ax.plot([1.5,2.5,3.5], color='blue', label='thin blue line')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I dislike this option because it is not clean and does not work generally. The second "hidden" subplot adds some padding that does not match the width of the legend. Long legend text could still be truncated.

Answer (score -2):

Store your legend call instance to a variable. e.g:

```
rr = sine_curve_plot.legend(loc=(0.0,1.1))
```

Then, include the `bbox_extra_artists`, `bbox_inches` keyword argument to `plt.savefig`. i.e:

```
plt.savefig('output.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', bbox_extra_artists=(rr))
```

`bbox_extra_artists` accepts an iterable, so you can include as many `legend` instances into it. The `bbox_extra_artists` automatically tells plt to cover every extra info passed into `bbox_extra_artists`.

DISCLAIMER: The `loc` variable simply defines the position of the legend, you can tweak the values for better flexibility in positioning. Of course, strings like `upper left`, `upper right`, etc. are also valid.