# Change the ticklabel orientation and legend position of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am plotting a bar graph by reading data from a CSV using pandas in Python. I read a CSV into a `DataFrame` and plot them using matplotlib.

Here is how my CSV looks like:

```
SegmentName    Sample1   Sample2   Sample3

Loop1          100       100       100

Loop2          100       100       100
```

---

```
res = DataFrame(pd.read_csv("results.csv", index_col="SegmentName"))
```

I plot and set the legend to be outside.

```
plt.figure()
ax = res.plot(kind='bar')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.savefig("results.jpg")
```

However, the x-axis ticklabels are orientated vertically and hence I can't read the text. Also my legend outside is cut off.

Can I change the orientation of the ticklabels to be horizontal, and then adjust the entire figure so that the legend is visible?

[image]

Comment: Ofcourse we need,

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: Include a link to your image, so we can update your question to include the image.

Comment: Here is the screenshot.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/srzn.jpg/

Comment: It seems you are trying to rotate the _ticklabels_ on the x-axis rather than the _label_, which is another object entirely. You should update your question to clarify.

Comment: Plot also has an argument. For example df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0) for horizontal orientation

Answer (score 11):

Try using the 'rotation' keyword when you set the label. E.g.:

```
plt.xlabel('hi',rotation=90)
```

Or if you need to rotate the tick labels, try:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

As for the positioning of the legend etc., it is probably worth taking a look at the [tight layout guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

Comment: This will rotate the ticklabels on the x-axis, not the axis label, so I believe this does not achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Either way, the 'rotation' keyword is the main point - it can be passed into a label function. Updating answer.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of my plot.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/srzn.jpg/

Comment: From the image provided by OP right now, it seems your first solution was correct after all; he is trying to rotate the _ticklabels_, not the label as he has written in his question.

Comment: Sorry, I used the above solution, but my plot still looks the same. I loop1, loop2 to be Horizontal orientation instead of vertical as shown in my figure.

Also, how do I change the plot size so that I can see my legend. They are cut off.

Comment: I've updated my answer which should help you out and point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `matplotlib` API and call `ax.set_xticklabels(res.index, rotation=0)` like so:

```
index = Index(['loop1', 'loop2'], name='segment_name')
data = [[100] * 3, [100] * 3]
columns = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3']
df = DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

fig, ax = subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', legend=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index, rotation=0)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
fig.savefig('results.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

to get the resulting plot:

[image]

Alternatively you can call `fig.autofmt_xdate()` for a nice tilted effect, which you can of course tinker with with the above (and more general) `ax.set_xticklabels()`:

```
fig, ax = subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', legend=False)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
fig.savefig('results-tilted.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: when I try and use ax = dataframe.plot() AND "ax.set_xticklabels(df.month_date, rotation=90)" I get the error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'. I just want my x axis label to rotate so the text reads the date, vertical from top to bottom!

Answer (score 5):

For the rotation of the labels, you can simply tell pandas to rotate it for you by giving the number of degrees to the `rot` argument.
The legends being cut off is answered elsewhere as well, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154763/1545579):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6])],
                              orient='index', columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', rot=90)
lgd = ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
fig.savefig("results.jpg", bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: This is definitely the best one. `rot` was what I was looking for