# Legend to the right of figure gets cut off from matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is extremely frustrating. Just as I figured out how to get a substantial legend OUT of my plot using the following:

```
plt.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.75))
```

Now the following command

```
plt.savefig(r'test'+'.jpeg', dpi=120*4)
```

outputs an image where the legend is almost completely cut off from the jpeg. I know its there since I can see part of it but the better part is missing.

How can I fix this please? I have tried to implement the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101700/moving-matplotlib-legend-outside-of-the-axis-makes-it-cutoff-by-the-figure-box) to no avail. Furthermore the situation is slightly different here since that question had a legendat the bottom of the `axes` and was not trying to save it to a `jpeg` like I am.

Comment: You can fix it by playing around with all the parameters available till it works.

Comment: Care to include a minimal set of your code that we can use to duplicate your figure?  It need not include the same data; just the same figure and axes size and enough lines to generate a similar-sized legend that causes the problem.