# why is the legend not present in the generated image if I use 'tight' for bbox_inches with the fig.legend method?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I am trying to produce an image where I put the legend outside of the axes. But I find that if I use `bbox_inches='tight'` in the `plt.savefig()` method, the generated image does not contain the legend. A minimal working example to illustrate is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)


fig, ax1= plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 6))

ax1.plot(x, y1, label='sin(x)')
ax1.plot(x, y2, label='cos(x)')

handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()

plt.figlegend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', ncol=2, frameon=False,
              bbox_to_anchor=(0.11, 0.95))

plt.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The produced `test.jpg` is shown below
[image: Image without legend]

If I remove `bbox_inches='tight'` in `savefig()` method.(shown below), the legend is present  in the produced image , but there are two much white space in the four side of the image.

[image]

Is there a good way to retain the tight layout of the image and also retain the legend in the generated image?

#### Edit 1

Following the instruction in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101700/moving-matplotlib-legend-outside-of-the-axis-makes-it-cutoff-by-the-figure-box), I also tried to use `bbox_extra_artists` argument in the `savefig()` method, something like this

```
legend = plt.figlegend(handles, labels, loc='lower left', ncol=2, frameon=True,
              bbox_to_anchor=(0.12, 0.88))
plt.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_extra_artists=(legend,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

As is pointed by @Diziet Asahi and @mportanceOfBeingErnest, if we use `ax.legend()` method, everything works fine. The following code works,

```
legend = ax1.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2, frameon=False,
                    loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.01, 1.2))
plt.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

#### Edit2

[According to the Matplotlib developer](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10194), there seems to be a bug that legend produced by `fig.legend` method are not taken into account when we use tight layout.

Comment: Any workarounds?

Comment: Just use `ax.legend()` instead of the `fig.legend()`.

Answer (score 3):

You may create the legend using the `.legend()` method of one of the figure's axes. In order to specify the legend coordinates in figure coordinates, as would be done using `figlegend` you may use the `bbox_transform` argument.

```
ax1.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper left', ncol=2, frameon=False,
              bbox_to_anchor=(0.11, 0.95), bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly why it happens (seems like a bug to me), but it looks like the problem is with your use of the top-level `plt.figlegend()` function. The problem persist if using `Figure.legend()`, but disappears if you replace it with `Axes.legend()`:

```
legend = ax1.legend(handles, labels, loc='lower left', ncol=2, frameon=False,
              bbox_to_anchor=(0,1.2))
fig.savefig('test.jpg', bbox_extra_artists=[legend], bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have also find that. Using `axes.legend()` method, I can save the image with the legend present without the `bbox_extra_artists` argument.