# How to plot two case1.hdf5 and case2.hdf5 files in matplotlib. Seeking help to correct the script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have below script which only plots `case1.hdf5` file.

- I want to plot another `case2.hdf5` file in  same script such that  I
  get two overlapping plots.

Additionally, I want to use

1. Times New Roman fonts for labels and titles.
2. Insert Legends for both the plots.
3. Multiply Y-axis data with some constant number.
4. This script gives bottom three lines in a same colour but I want all
   three in different solid colours  for case1.hdf5 and with same
   colour and dashed for another case2.hdf5 file.

## My script is here

```
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import warnings
import matplotlib

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # Ignore all warnings


ticklabels=[r'$\Gamma$','F','Q','Z',r'$\Gamma$']

params = {
'mathtext.default': 'regular',
'axes.linewidth': 1.2,
'axes.edgecolor': 'Black',
}

plt.rcParams.update(params)
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

f = h5py.File('band.hdf5',  'r')
#print ('datasets are:')
print(list(f.keys()))

dist=f[u'distance']
freq=f[u'frequency']
kpt=f[u'path']

# Iterate over each segment
for i in range(len(dist)):
# Iteraton over each band
    for nbnd in range(len(freq[i][0])):
        x=[]
        y=[]

        for j in range(len(dist[i])):
            x.append(dist[i][j])
            y.append(freq[i][j][nbnd])
# First 3 bands are red
        if (nbnd<3):
            color='red'
        else:
            color='black'

        ax.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=2.0, alpha=0.8)

# Labels and axis limit and ticks
ax.set_ylabel(r'Frequency (THz)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel(r'Wave Vector (q)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlim([dist[0][0],dist[len(dist)-1][-1]])
xticks=[dist[i][0] for i in range(len(dist))]
xticks.append(dist[len(dist)-1][-1])
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
# Plot grid
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', c='green', lw=2.5, linestyle='--', alpha=0.8)
# Save to pdf
plt.savefig('plots.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

You see, there is

## First 3 bands are red

```
    if (nbnd<3):
        color='red'
```

and instead of red I want all of these three in solid different colours and for `case2.hdf5` in dashed lines with same colours.

Comment: I'm not behind a keyboard rn. But as for the other file, it seams like you want to alternate between black and red lines. In that case I would use the modulo operator (%) within the outer most loop (i think, could be inner loop tbh) to set the color of the line. Something like 'ax.plot(..., color="r" if i % 2 else "k")'...notice you can use shorthand 'r' for 'red' and 'k' for 'black'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Colours

It sounds like in the first instance you want to map different colours to the first there bands of your data.

One way you might do this is to [setup a colourmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html) and then apply it to those first three bands. Here I have just picked the default matplotlib colormap, but there are loads to choose from, so if the default doesn't work for you I would suggest checking out the post about [choosing a colormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). In most use cases you should try to stick to a perceptually constant map.

## 2. Legend

This should just be a matter of calling `ax.legend()`. Although be wary when setting the position of the legend to be outside the bounds of the plot as you need to do some extra finicking when saving to pdf, [as detailed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154763/2727632).

However you first need to add some labels to your plot, which in your case you would do inside your `ax.plot()` calls. I'm not sure what you are plotting, so can't tell you what labels would be sensible, but you may want something like: `ax.plot(... label=f'band {nbnd}' if nbnd < 4 else None)`.

Notice the inline `if`. You are likely going to have a whole bunch of black bands that you don't want to label individually, so you likely want to only label the first and let the rest have `label = None` which means no bloated legend.

## 3. Scale Y

If you change the way you iterate through your data you should be able to capture the h5 dataset as something that behaves much like a numpy array. What I mean by that is you really only need two loops to index the data you want. `freq[i, :, nbnd]` should be a 1-d array that you want to set to `y`. You can multiply that 1-d array by some `scale` value

## 4.

```py
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import warnings
import matplotlib

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # Ignore all warnings

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet', 4)

ticklabels=['A','B','C','D','E']

params = {
'mathtext.default': 'regular',
'axes.linewidth': 1.2,
'axes.edgecolor': 'Black',
'font.family' : 'serif'
}


#get the viridis cmap with a resolution of 3

#apply a scale to the y axis. I'm just picking an arbritrary number here
scale = 10
offset = 0 #set this to a non-zero value if you want to have your lines offset in a waterfall style effect


plt.rcParams.update(params)
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 

f = h5py.File('band.hdf5',  'r')
#print ('datasets are:')
print(list(f.keys()))

dist=f[u'distance']
freq=f[u'frequency']
kpt=f[u'path']

lbl = {0:'AB', 1:'BC', 2:'CD', 3:'fourth'}

for i, section in enumerate(dist):
    for nbnd, _ in enumerate(freq[i][0]):
        x = section # to_list() you may need to convert sample to list.
        y = (freq[i, :, nbnd] + offset*nbnd) * scale

        if (nbnd<3):
            color=f'C{nbnd}'
        else:
            color='black'

        ax.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=2.0, alpha=0.8, label = lbl[nbnd] if nbnd < 3 and i == 0 else None)


ax.legend()

# Labels and axis limit and ticks
ax.set_ylabel(r'Frequency (THz)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel(r'Wave Vector (q)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlim([dist[0][0],dist[len(dist)-1][-1]])
xticks=[dist[i][0] for i in range(len(dist))]
xticks.append(dist[len(dist)-1][-1])
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
# Plot grid
ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', c='green', lw=2.5, linestyle='--', alpha=0.8)
# Save to pdf
plt.savefig('plots.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

This script gives me the following image with the data you supplied
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215060/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-micallef-how-to-plot-two-case1-hdf5-and-case2-hdf).