# Non-overlapping legend and axes (e.g. in matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need the plot legend to appear side-by-side to the plot axes, i.e. **outside of the axes and non-overlapping**.

The width of the `axes` and the `legend` should adjust "automatically" so that they both fill the figure w/o them to overlap or the legend to be cut, even when using [tight layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html). The legend should occupy a minor portion of the figure (let's say max to 1/3 of figure width so that the remaining 2/3 are dedicated to the actual plot).

Eventually, the font of the legend entries can automatically reduce to meet the requirements.

I've read a number of answers regarding `legend` and `bbox_to_anchor` in matplotlib with no luck, among which:

- [how to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/7074426)
- [moving matplotlib legend outside of the axis makes it cutoff by the figure box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101700/moving-matplotlib-legend-outside-of-the-axis-makes-it-cutoff-by-the-figure-box)

I tried by creating a dedicated axes in which to put the legend so that plt.tight_layout() would do its job properly but then the legend only takes a minor portion of the dedicated axes, with the result that a lot of space is wasted. Or if there isn't enough space (the figure is too small), the legend overlaps the first axes anyway.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some data
x = np.arange(1, 100) 

# create 2 side-by-side axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
# create a plot with a long legend 
for ii in range(20):
    ax[0].plot(x, x**2, label='20201110_120000')
    ax[0].plot(x, x, label='20201104_110000')

# grab handles and labels from the first ax and pass it to the second
hl = ax[0].get_legend_handles_labels() 
leg = ax[1].legend(*hl, ncol=2)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I'm open to use a package different from matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to plot the legend in a separate axis, you can pass `loc` to `legend`:

```
# create 2 side-by-side axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
# create a plot with a long legend 
for ii in range(20):
    ax.plot(x, x**2, label='20201110_120000')
    ax.plot(x, x, label='20201104_110000')

# grab handles and labels from the first ax and pass it to the second
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc=[1,0])
plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I tried this option with the `Figure legend` instead of the `Axes legend`, which is not good. Using `loc=[1, 0]` with the `Figure legend` puts the legend outside the Figure itself, thus it's invisible. Using `Axes legend` works as expected.